# Post data from javascript to php file using ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I tried to used ajax to post data from javascript file to php file, there was nothing displayed on php file after using

> $_POST['userinput']

Here is the javascript file:

```
 searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        userinput = places[0].name.toString();  // Get user input from search box

        // Pass data to userinput.php via ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'userinput.php',
            data: {userinput : userinput},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });

    });
```

php file:

```
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "XXXXXXX";
        $password = "XXXXXXXXX";
        $dbname = "CALIFORNIA";

        $city = $_POST['userinput']; // Nothing is posted here

        // Create connection
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, 1);


        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT State FROM  CITY as C WHERE   C.City_name=$city");
        $sql->execute();

        $result = $sql->fetchAll();
        $json = json_encode($result);
        echo $json;
    }
```

I was able to connect to the mysql database. However, there was no data posted from javascript file to php. I'm not sure what to do from this point. the value **$city** print out nothing. On the client side it printed out an empty object.

Comment: alert(userinput); and check what it returns . it will alert your search text input or not ?

Comment: `data: {'userinput' : userinput},` quotes missed

Comment: I tried that, didn't work either

Comment: the client side accept the search text fine. It's just that nothing is posted on php file

Comment: @Anant quotes or no quotes do not change anything in this case. Quotes are useful only when setting a key name that is note a valid JS identifier (Ex: `not-valid`, because of the dash)

Comment: show us value of `userinput`

Comment: var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        userinput = places[0].name.toString(); varify userinput variable has proper value or not

Comment: have you check the userinput value in client side.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user input...

Comment: https://interactive-map-electro2k-1.c9users.io/interact-map.php Here is the userinput on the client side in the search box

Comment: use dataType: "json" in your ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ajax function try setting `dataType` property

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'userinput.php',
            data: {'userinput' : 'userinput'},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text", // add this property
            success: function (result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });
```

Comment: it turn out to be that PHP does not allow RAW_POST anymore. the code is fine though

Comment: this may help you. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php